# Replacing input text when tab is pressed ( Chrome Extension )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So basically what I'm trying to do is identify if the input bar has "y" typed in it and when tab key is pressed replace that y with "youtube ".

Javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
var words = input.split(" ");

$("#searchbar").keydown(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(input == 'y') {
        $('#searchbar').text('youtube');
    }
}
});
```

Currently I'm not getting any error messages, its just not working. The tab key also moves the focus away from the input bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why

1. You should be getting value on keydown , not on page load as at the time of loading page value is empty.
2. As you are using jquery , get current value of input using jquery facade/selector
3. Finally you update the input box value not text

### Try this

```js
    $("#searchbar").keydown(function(e) {
      var input = $('#searchbar').val();
      var words = input.split(" ");

     if(e.keyCode == 9) {
      if(input == 'y') {
        $('#searchbar').val('youtube');
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter Search Term
<input type="text" id="searchbar">
```

Comment: It isn't working, but maybe I should try putting this script in background.js since it is a chrome extension